# Why does the gulp command prompt attempt to open the gulp.js via the OS shell?

Tags: node.js, gulp

While attempting to try out gulp for nodejs and just following their hello world equivalent instructions, I was seeing the gulp.js file appear in Brackets when I ran 'gulp'. So I uninstalled Brackets and now I am prompted for what to open the js file with. (See screenshot.) I'm perplexed by this behavior and suspect that between the nodejs installer, the npm installer, and the gulp installer via npm, there was a bug along the way. For what it's worth, running "gulp" without a gulp.js file gives a proper "No gulpfile found" error and other tools like "bower" and "grunt" run just fine, globally installed.

[image: gulp screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's `gulpfile.js` not `gulp.js`. Rename it and it will works well.